# SpriteKit SKTextures

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktexture

```
        for building in self.buildingArray {
        if building.contains(location) {
            upgradeArray.removeAll()
            upgradeArray.append(building)
            for tower in self.upgradeArray {
                print(tower.position.x)
                let buildingExample = SKSpriteNode()
                buildingExample.texture = tower.texture
                buildingExample.position.y = spikeTowerOption.position.y
                buildingExample.position.x = 0
                buildingExample.zPosition = 20
                buildingExample.setScale(frame.size.height/3700)
                self.addChild(buildingExample)
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue here is about the textures. I can't figure out how to properly take the towers texture and make the buildingExample have it's same texture. Currently, the building example is not visibly appearing on the screen.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Where does `tower.texture` come from?

Comment: The tower is the sprite in the building array that is touched, so the tower.texture would be the texture of that sprite.

Comment: try init SKSpriteNode from any SKSpriteNode inits : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode

For example: SKSpriteNode(texture: tower.texture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
            let buildingExample = SKSpriteNode()
            buildingExample.texture = tower.texture
```

For:

```
            let buildingExample = SKSpriteNode(texture: tower.texture)
```